# Issues with Binary expression in swift

Tags: swift, ios8, xcode6

I want to know about the difference between the Equal(==) and identical(===) expressions. Also why we are using pattern match (~=) expression. Where can I use these expressions. Can anyone explain please. Thanks in advance.

My sample code is:

```
  var sample1 = "Steve jobs"
  var sample2 = "Steve jobs"
  sample1 === sample2 ? println("Its Equal"):println("Not equal") //result "Not equal"

 var sample3 = "Steve jobs"
 var sample4 = "Steve jobs"
 sample3 == sample4 ? println("Its Equal"):println("Not equal")//result "Its Equal"
```

The use of other Binary expressions with good examples will always be welcome. I think pattern match does not exist in objective c.

Comment: the `===` is compares whether the two references point to the _same_ instance in memory; the `==` depends on the actual objects, but it is usually used for comparing the _values_ of the instance(s). the official docs can explain it if you read it: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-XID_70

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example you have written cannot be even compiled

[image]

And that's because `===` is defined only for *object types* but Swift `String` is a *value type*.

In general, it means that two object intances are the same instance. While `==` checks the equality of the contents.

You can use `===` only with `NSString` instances which are object types:

```
var sample1: NSString = "string1"
var sample2: NSString = "string1"

sample1 === sample2  //false
```

The pattern matching expression `~=` is used by the `switch - case` control statement. The `switch(value)` defines a value and every `case pattern:` defines a pattern to match. The `~=` function is called for every `case` to decide if the `case` statements should be executed or no.

Answer (score 1):

From [Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-XID_70):

> Swift also provides two identity operators (=== and !==), which you use to test whether two object references both refer to the **same object instance**.

In your case `sample1` and `sample2` have different instances

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, `sample1` and `sample2` are two different string instances, therefore `sample1 === sample2` yields `false` (as they are NOT the same object)

On the other hand, sample3 and sample4 are EQUAL STRINGS, and therefore, `sample3 == sample4` yields `true` (as these two instances represent the SAME STRING)

Answer (score 1):

First is "Not Equal" because sample1 and sample2 have the same content but are TWO DIFFERENT objects.

Second is "Its Equal" because samle3 and sample4 have the same content.

`==` stands for "comparing by value" or comparing content

`===` stands for "comparing by reference" or ensure two references are pointing to the same object.